# Unable to mount External HD - Mac OS Extended

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, mount, error

UPDATE: I am able to recover quite a bit with Disk Drill it seems. I'm hoping this proves fruitful. Thanks to those who offered insight!

For context, I've been asked to provide footage for a client dating to before I worked here. I found this archive drive from the year in question and found that it was inaccessible. I keep better storage systems than the previous employees and have helped with our storage organization quite a bit since joining.

ORIGINAL POST:
I am trying to access some footage on an external HD. The volume will not mount. Each time I try to mount the volume, I get the error "Could not mount "{Drive Name}". com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error 49244.) I attempted to run first aid, and received this response:

[image]

I read on a similar post to Add APFS Volume (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382541/428568). In my instance, I only have the option to "Convert to APFS"

I'm not able to create a backup of the disk, and I need to access footage contained on the drive. Would converting to APFS damage the contents of the drive?

I'm also open to any guidance for additional steps I can try.

Thanks in advance,
Taylor

Comment: Never attempt to convert to another format something which is already broken in the original format. It will not end well.

Comment: I feared as much. Thank you for your response!

Comment: If/when you successfully mount and remove data from this disk, _chuck the disk in the trash_. Don't re-use it. External HDs are relatively inexpensive. Important stuff like this needs to be in the cloud, too.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you can take to this.

- Fix the drive using better tools than fsck. [DiskWarrior](https://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) has always been the go-to tool for this. It will not damage the drive further, as it makes 'virtual' fixes which you can test before committing the changes. Disk Warrior is great on HFS+ but cannot handle APFS.
- Rescue the drive to another drive. [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com) is a good tool for this. It will scavenge the drive for any undamaged data then allow you to copy that off to another drive. This should also leave the original unchanged.
- Copy the data off, as is & try to recover once you know you have a copy. Using the built-in `dd` command to literally copy all data, byte for byte across to another drive. Instructions at [My External Hard Drive's format changed to FAT16 without any reason](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348539/my-external-hard-drives-format-changed-to-fat16-without-any-reason)
  This still requires you to perform the rescue using Disk Drill or similar, but working on a safety copy.
- Give the drive to a data rescue professional.

Comment: I'm currently 5 hours into a deep scan with Disk Drill. It is recovering a ton of stuff so far, and I am encouraged. Time will tell if the footage I need is actually on this device. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have run across an issue with an external HFS+ disk that Disk Utility can't fix.

You *could* try running disk utility again a time or three but I would bet you get the same results. I have seen running Disk Utility repair multiple times actually fix the problem *sometimes*.

You will likely need to look into a third party disk repair utility. My **go-to** on that front used to be DiskWarrior. But it can't handle APFS volumes (yet, supposedly). That is not an issue for this specific use case as it *could* repair that volume.

If you want a utility that *might* fix that volume **and fix future problems with APFS** TechTool Pro (I believe) supports APFS and may be able to repair the volume.

Note that no disk utility is guaranteed to be able to fix any disk issue like yours, but they generally do a better job than Apple's Disk Utility.app and will *usually* be able to fix the issue.

Comment: I've seen several people recommend Disk Warrior. I'm currently doing a deep scan with Disk Drill that seems to be recovering quite a bit. If that fails for some reason, I'll check out Disk Warrior. Thanks!